# Find a column from a file in another file based on value and order

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have two files and would like to find out which parts of file 1 occur in the same order/sequence of file 2 based on one of multiple columns (col4). The files are sorted based on an identifier in col1 (from 1 to n) but the identifier is not the between the files. The column in file 1 always occurs as one block in file 2.

file1:

```
x 1
x 2
x 3
```

file2:

```
y 5
y 1
y 2 
y 3
y 6
```

output:

```
y 1
y 2
y 3
```

Another thing to take into consideration is, that the entries in the column to be filtered on are not unique.

I already tried

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ a[$2]=$2;next } ($2 in a)' file1 file2 > output
```

but it only works if you have unique identifiers.

To clarify it with real life data: I would like to extract the rows where I have the same order based on column 4.

File1:

```
ATOM     13  O   ALA A   2      37.353  35.331 -19.903  1.00 71.02           O  

ATOM     18  O   TRP A   3      38.607  32.133 -18.273  1.00 69.13           O
```

File2:

```
ATOM      1  N   MET A   1      42.218  38.990 -18.511  1.00 64.21           N

ATOM     10  CA  ALA A   2      38.451  37.475 -20.033  1.00 71.02           C

ATOM     13  O   ALA A   2      37.353  35.331 -19.903  1.00 71.02           O

ATOM     18  O   TRP A   3      38.607  32.133 -18.273  1.00 69.13           O

ATOM     29  CA  ILE A   4      38.644  33.633 -15.907  1.00 72.47           C
```

Comment: The question lacks some important information: Are the files sorted? How? Can matches in `file2` be interleaved with unrelated data or do they always occur as compact blocks?

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek Thanks for your feedback, i added the info to the post!

Comment: Try changing your `awk` to the following: `awk 'FNR==NR{ a[$2]=$2;next } ($2 in a)' file1 file2`.

Comment: @j_b Thanks for your suggestion, I just realized that I forgot to adapt the code for my example. That is exactly what I already tried.

Comment: Can you edit your question with sample data illustrating "the entries in the column to be filtered on are not unique"?

Comment: @j_b Yes of course!

Comment: There is way too much data there now. Please review the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: Are the empty lines there in the actual files?  It makes it more difficult...

Comment: @Nic3500 Yes, they are actually empty but one can access the columns directly via the $ sign

Comment: This `awk` might work for you: `awk 'FNR==NR && NF { a[$4]=$4;next } ($4 in a)&&!seen[$4]++' file1 file2`.

Comment: @j_b Thanks for your help! unfortunately, this did not work as well and i decided to write a short R script to circumvent this issue.